# Mouse and keyboard input and audio output doesn't work in X11 window

Tags: keyboard, unix, mouse, x11, third-party

Through some form of dark magic, I was able to make a Linux X11 QT/GTK2 (I don't know which one) application compile and run on my 2021 MacBook Pro running macOS 14.1. All the windows open fine, but the PulseAudio driver fails to load (pretty important since this is an audio program) and I can't use the mouse or keyboard to click the buttons in the X11 window.

Why is it not working, and how do I fix it?

Here is a [video](https://vimeo.com/882109090?share=copy) of what happens when I try to interact with the window. (in the video, I am using the keyboard and mouse buttons, but nothing happens)